# Reason for the Choice of Line Parameters in the Radon Transform

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, integral-transforms

Why are the lines, over which the integrals in a Radon Transform are calculated, apparently always parameterized as $L(t,\phi,\alpha) := (t*\sin(\alpha)+s*\cos(\alpha),-t*\cos(\alpha)+s*\sin(\alpha))$, (cf e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) resp. have other kinds of line-parameterization ever been investigated?

What are the practical and mathematical issues that are related to different kinds of parameterization (positive and negative)?

Did Radon himself loose any words about the choice of line-parameterization?

Comment: Have you read Radon's original paper? I don't understand German well enough, but you could take a look at it: http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/courses/papers/Exact_Conebeam/Radon_Deutsch_1917.pdf

Comment: It is possible to parametrize the lines by base point and direction. This parametrization is redundant (by one dimension), but there is no preferred point or direction. One can invert the Radon transform in this parametrization as well.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta thanks for the pointer to the article; I will have a look and maybe report on any findings.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I just glanced over Radon's original article and did not find any discussion of alternative line parameterizations; he used the commonly used parameterization without giving any reason for that particular choice.

Comment: Since the group of isometries of the plane acts transitively on the space of affine lines, up to a multiplicative constant, there is only one  measure on the space of  affine lines that is invariant  with respect to this action. This is the measure used in the Radon formula, and the precise  form of the parametrization of the space of affine lines is irrelevant.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu there are however differences in the "visual effects" of different parameterizations; in $(t,\alpha)$ coordinates the Radon transform of a point is a sine-curve; if one would use $(t*\cos(\alpha),t*\sin(\alpha))$ instead (i.e. map lines to their point nearest to the origin), the Radon transform would be a circle, which is a geometrically much simpler shape, plus the Radon transform then is an automorphism of disks centered at the origin and no meaningles quantities like negative radii or angle ranges bigger than $2\pi$ are encountered.

Comment: @ManfredWeis I do not understand   what you mean by  *the Radon transform of a point*. The Radon transform, as I know it, maps (generalized) functions to (generalized) functions.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu sorry for my imprecise formulation; what I had in mind was a 2D Dirac $\delta$ function, that vanishes everywhere, except at a single point; the Radon transform is then non-vanishing on a circle instead of a sine-curve.

Comment: @Manfred Weis I get it. First,you need to be careful with the concept of  distribution/generalized function: on a manifold they are different concepts. That aside, check  chapter I of  Helgason's book *The Radon transform*.   He computes the Radon transform  of the delta-function in section 5 and obtains an invariant description: it is the invariant measure supported along the curve defined by the lines passing through the origin. This description is clearly  coordinate independent.